# Is it possible to change the thickness of lines in an svg without using an editor like Illustrator?

Tags: svg

I have this svg:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 286.054 286.054" style="enable-background:new 0 0 286.054 286.054;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px" class=""><g><g>
     <path d="M143.027,0C64.031,0,0,64.04,0,143.027c0,78.996,64.031,143.027,143.027,143.027   s143.027-64.031,143.027-143.027C286.054,64.04,222.022,0,143.027,0z M143.027,259.236c-64.183,0-116.209-52.026-116.209-116.209   S78.844,26.818,143.027,26.818s116.209,52.026,116.209,116.209S207.21,259.236,143.027,259.236z" data-original="#2394BC" class="active-path" data-old_color="#2394BC" fill="#999999"/>
     <path d="M150.026,80.39h-22.84c-6.91,0-10.933,7.044-10.933,13.158c0,5.936,3.209,13.158,10.933,13.158   h7.259v85.36c0,8.734,6.257,13.605,13.176,13.605s13.185-4.881,13.185-13.605V92.771C160.798,85.789,156.945,80.39,150.026,80.39z" data-original="#2394BC" class="active-path" data-old_color="#2394BC" fill="#999999"/>
    </g></g> </svg>
```

It's a simple outer circle with a number in the center.

[image]

What I would like to know is if it's possible to change the width of the outer circle with editing the source or is that something that can only be done with Adobe illustrator or a similar tool?

Comment: The paths have no stroke. What you have are filled paths. You may try to add a stroke the the circle the same color as the fill (`stroke="#999999"`) although you can replace the path with a `<circle>` element with no fill and a stroke

Comment: Please try `<circle r="130" cx="143" cy="143" fill="none" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="25" />` instead of the path and change the `stroke-width` as you need

Comment: @enxaneta Will you fill out the answer? The fact is that I have exactly the same answer as your comments, plus a picture. If you want to draw up your answer, I will only glad

Comment: @Alexandr_TT please add your answer and the picture too

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for your comments and the opportunity to answer me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented @enxaneta

> The paths have no stroke. What you have are filled paths. You may try
>   to add a stroke the the circle the same color as the fill
>   (stroke="#999999") although you can replace the path with a 
>   element with no fill and a stroke
>
> Please try `<circle r="130" cx="143" cy="143" fill="none"
>   stroke="#999999" stroke-width="25" />`
>    instead of the path and change
>   the stroke-width as you need

[image]

As you can see in the figure, path has a double contour which is painted over.
Instead of path, add a circle.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px"  viewBox="0 0 286.054 286.054" style="enable-background:new 0 0 286.054 286.054;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px" class=""><g><g>
    <circle r="130" cx="143" cy="143" fill="none" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="25"  data-original="#2394BC" class="active-path" data-old_color="#2394BC" />
    <path d="M150.026,80.39h-22.84c-6.91,0-10.933,7.044-10.933,13.158c0,5.936,3.209,13.158,10.933,13.158   h7.259v85.36c0,8.734,6.257,13.605,13.176,13.605s13.185-4.881,13.185-13.605V92.771C160.798,85.789,156.945,80.39,150.026,80.39z" data-original="#2394BC" class="active-path" data-old_color="#2394BC" fill="#999999"/>
</g></g> </svg>
```